# Using the command line tool to check models

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I made a very simple model and am trying to query from it from the Django command line tool. My model is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Finish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    finish = models.ForeignKey('Finish', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Here's an entry from the Finish model:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "chrome",
    "date_created": "2018-04-21T21:26:24.214581Z",
    "date_modified": "2018-04-21T21:26:24.214581Z"
}
```

Here's an entry from the Widget model:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "New Chrome Widget",
    "inventory": 123,
    "date_created": "2018-04-21T21:27:57.774508Z",
    "date_modified": "2018-04-21T22:01:46.177778Z",
    "finish": 1
}
```

And this is what I'm getting back:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from api.models import *
>>> f = Finish.objects.all()
>>> w = Widget.objects.all()
>>> f
<QuerySet [<Finish: chrome>, <Finish: matte>, <Finish: translucent>, <Finish: silicone>, <Finish: gold>, <Finish: gold-plated>]>
>>> w
<QuerySet [<Widget: New Chrome Widget>, <Widget: Discontinued Matte Widget>, <Widget: Extreme Edition>]>
>>> f.widget_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'widget_set'
```

The documentation says for a given model instance the child attribute name is composed of the model name in lower case + `_set` but this isn't working for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that `f` is a `QuerySet` and not an object.

from Django Docs(without the gaps):

`>>> a.reporter
<Reporter: John Smith>`

`>>> r = a.reporter`

`>>> r.article_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: John's second story>, <Article: Paul's story>, <Article: This is a test>]>`

Try:

`f = Finish.objects.get(pk=1)`

`f.widget_set.all()`

and you should get your desired results.